# DNS entry for third level domain

Tags: apache, ubuntu, dns, virtualhost

I am trying to create a third-level domain virtual host on my server. I hope the configs are set up correctly, but I am getting a `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error.

I have read that I have to "add DNS entry" somewhere so that the name would get resolved, but how do I do that? Where do I do that? The server is running on Ubuntu .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you get that `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error from Chrome. This means that Chrome is unable to find the subdomain in DNS.

You are correct, registering your subdomain in DNS will require DNS changes. Specifically, you have to add a DNS `A` resource record for your subdomain to become "visible" to browsers over IPv4. For IPv6, add an `AAAA`, too. Both record types point to an IP address and it will be the IP address of your web server. (Technically, you can also use a `CNAME` type record, but make sure to read up on how that works.)

Subdomain DNS will be served by the authoritative DNS servers for your domain, so you can register the required record(s) through your DNS service provider. If you are not sure who they are, look up the `NS` records for your domain, this will give you the list of authoritative name servers for your domain and you can work from there.

I understand you have already configured your Apache to work with the subdomain, so setting up DNS completes the setup process.

Comment: If this needs to be done through the DNS providers, is that generally a free service? I hope it should be, since that seems to be the whole point to me, but I rather ask

Comment: @MartinMelka: I don't know of any DNS provider who would charge for subdomains, but who knows. In any case, you can always consult your DNS provider.